# Puppeteer generate blank pdf - (using .setContent)

Tags: javascript, express, vuejs3, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer 19.5.2. I am trying to generate a buffer at the BE(Express server) and send it back to the FE which creates a blob from the buffer and downloaded it. But everytime I am getting blank pdf page. After the content is added, I checked it with `page.content()` and everything looks ok. I am using Headless mode.

this is the code from the BE

```
  export default async function generatePDF(req, res): Promise<void> {
  const params = req.body;
 
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    defaultViewport: { width: 794, height: 1123 },
    headless: true,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(generateHTML(params), {
    waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0', 'networkidle2'],
  });
  //const content = await page.content();
  //console.log(content, 'content');
 
  await page.addStyleTag({ content: STYLES });
  await page.waitForSelector('div', { visible: true });
 
  await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
  const pdf = await page.pdf({
    margin: { top: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10, left: 10 },
    width: '794px',
    height: '1123px',
  });
 
  await browser.close();
  res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', 'Content-Length': pdf.length });
  res.send(pdf);
}
 
function generateHTML(params): string {
  return `<div class="wrapper">
    <p>${params.username}</p>
    <p>${params.selectedDepartment}</p>
    <p>${params.selectedPositionName}</p>
  </div>
  `;
}
const STYLES = `
.wrapper {
  width: 794px;
  background-color: red;
}
`;
```

this is the code from the FE

```
const pdf = await downloadPDF(info);
const blob = new Blob([pdf.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = `your-file-name.pdf`;
link.click();
```

I'm trying to generate a pdf based on user input but every time I get an empty pdf file.

Comment: What's `downloadPDF` defined as? If you navigate directly to the endpoint (I assume it's a GET), does the PDF download work? You should be able to isolate the problem to either the backend or the frontend easily.